# Force Git to not commit and/or upload changes to a specific file to master

Tags: git

I have a [git](/questions/tagged/git) project where I have to do some changes to one file to get it working on a specific machine. This file is part of the repository and I don't want the file to be committed and uploaded to master unless i specifically tell it so. I want that or I want a command or option that I have to execute before committing and pushing so that the changes does not get uploaded to master.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said the file is already in the repository, the specific command that you want to not track changes to the specific file is

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged filename.ext
```

where filename.ext is the name of your specific file.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) is a good reference with examples. The only problem I've run into is ignoring  directories, be sure to include the trailing slash.

Comment: This won't help OP, as the file is present on the server, and he wants to track the changes to the file made upstream. He just doesn't want to change it himself.

Comment: Actually, in the bottom of the suggested document to read there is information about how to do what I want to do. Nice document to read.

Comment: user4815162342 is right I misunderstood the question. As dumb luck would have it that link does address the issue (a more specific answer is already posted). I've found that link useful more than once.